# circuitikz label malfunction

Tags: positioning, labels, circuitikz

This may be a total newbie problem, but I cannot find a single reference of this behaviour anywhere I look and thus this question:

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to[battery, l=12<\volt>] (0,2) -- (0,3.5)
                to[R] (4,3.5) -- (4,2)
          (0,0) -- (4,0) to[battery, l=24<\volt>] (4,2)
          (0,2) to[R, *-*] (2,2)
                to[R, -*] (4,2)
          (2,0) to[R, *-] (2,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The result I get is both labels overlapped at the lower left corner of the picture; the only way I can look at the image is with `xdvi`; any other document viewer like `evince` shows just the text, not the image. If another label is included in the code above, it goes like the others and ends overlapped at the lower left corner of the picture. It doesn't matter where or what is labelled: voltages, currents, capacitors, sources, ... it ends at the same place with the others at the lower left corner of the picture.

Yesterday I updated TeXLive from CTAN. No dice. I can send the resulting .dvi file if someone is kind enough to tell me how can I include a file to the question or if there is a place where I can upload it for you to see it like `Dropbox`.

Comment: Works fine with `pdflatex`, do you have to compile via DVI? (Not really an answer, I know.)

Comment: Once you convert the `.dvi` file to `.pdf`, the labels are correctly placed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DVI viewers are not able to understand the graphics commands used by TikZ/PGF for placing and drawing things. So viewing with a DVI viewer is a painful experience.

Compile with `pdflatex` and view with a PDF viewer.