# Customizing arrow types in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, circuitikz

Here is my MWE taken from [Flow of current in a circuit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127875/flow-of-current-in-a-circuit), except for the additional current direction at battery as well as one additional arrow mark using `\draw [<-, >=latex]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \draw [<-, >=latex] (-1.3,0.8)--(-1.3,1.3);
    \draw (0,0) to[battery, l=12<\volt>, i>^=$I_{B}$, >=latex] (0,2) -- (0,3.5)
                to[R,l=4<\ohm>,i_=$I_1$] (4,3.5) -- (4,2)
          (0,0) -- (4,0) to[battery, l=24<\volt>,i>] (4,2)
          (0,2) to[R, l=2<\ohm>, *-*,i_=$I_2$] (2,2)
                to[R, l=3<\ohm>, -*,i<_=$I_3$] (4,2)
          (2,0) to[R, l=2.5<\ohm>, *-,i<_=$I_4$] (2,2);
         % \draw[ultra  thin,color=gray!30, step=1cm, ] (0,0) grid (6,4);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

How to use `>=latex` locally within circuitikz such that, arrow tips of current flow directions through all elements look like the arrow mark shown left of the battery?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: Still I could not solve these my issue. It is giving errors

Comment: You could ask about these errors. Include your code in the question. Include the error description and include a link to where you got the solution(that is not working).

Comment: Anyway, `circuitikz` arrows are not arrows in the Ti*k*Z sense, they are shapes. If you want to use different types of arrows, look at the "advanced voltage and currents".